# Open Liberty : sessionCache for SIP session

Tags: session, sip, open-liberty, sip-servlet

I would like to know if the functionnality described in the article [JCache session persistence](https://openliberty.io/blog/2018/03/22/distributed-in-memory-session-caching.html) is applicable for SIP session as well ?
If not, is there an other way to synchronize sip session between Open Liberty instances ?

Thanks,
Clément.

Answer (score 0):

The `sessionCache-1.0` feature described in the blog post you've linked to will not work with SIP sessions - Liberty does not directly support SIP replication or failover. Your best option currently is to use a load balancer with health checking support.

Comment: Allright, thanks for your answer !